# Why do I get value by KVC but not by using properties while using Realm?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, realm, kvc

I am trying [Realm](https://realm.io/)(installed using pods). I am using Swift 3 with Xcode 8.1.

My code looks like this-

```
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        let human = Human()
        human.name = "Nikhil"
        human.legs = 2

        try realm.write {
            realm.add(human)
        }

        let humans = realm.objects(Human.self)
        for h in humans {
            print("\(h.name)") //Here is breakpoint
        }
    } catch {
        //
    }
```

And then I do

```
(lldb) po h.name
""


(lldb) po h.value(forKey: "name")!
Nikhil
```

Why are properties not returning values but I can retrieve values by `value(forKey:`?

Comment: LLDB should be able to `po` properties on Realm models directly; at least it worked for me with Xcode 8.2 and Realm installed using CocoaPods. Can you try clearing your derived data and cleaning your build folder (Option key + Product menu, then `Clean Build Folder...`)? Maybe there's some sort of cached data that's causing the debugger to not work properly.

Comment: That is probably because the model's properties aren't declared with `dynamic`. Without `dynamic` attribute, Swift property access will be static dispatch. Since Realm lazily loads all values, it needs dynamic dispatching. Please see our model definition cheatsheet https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#cheatsheet

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi You were right. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @kishikawa katsumi -

Class properties should have been defined as `dynamic`.

A big thanks to him for pointing that mistake.